# Is there a way to kill yourself immediately?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to kill yourself immediately in Minecraft? Without using normal methods like dropping sand or gravel on top of yourself or letting mobs attack you without fighting back, something like the `kill` command in Quake-like games?

Comment: Good question, but I think you can't.

Comment: not without the use of creepers sssssss **BOOM**

Comment: Suicide is a noun not a verb. You should ask about 'committing suicide' rather than 'suicide.'

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suicide?show=2&t=1308447592

Noun, verb and adj apparntly.

Comment: I'd like to add to this.  As of the last pre-release, 12w16, you can enable "Cheat Mode" within the World Settings, then in game use the /kill method, as described below.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you are playing SMP, [December 1st, 2010 update](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/2060360123/bug-update-4-and-were-six-people-in-the-office-now) removed the `/home` command, and [December 3rd, 2010 update](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/2082284675/bug-update-5-and-we-need-videos) added a `/kill` command, which will kill you upon issuance.

In SSP, there is no 'immediate' way to kill yourself without some additional setup, or handy terrain.

Comment: (/kill now works on singleplayer, as long as you created the word with cheats enabled)

Answer (score 18):

Just stack about 25 blocks underneath you by jumping & placing a block underneath you (at the height of your jump). After your stack is built sufficiently high, simply step off the edge to your death. This stack can be made of dirt, sand, or any block which you have an excess of at the moment.

Once you work out how many blocks you have to stack before the fall will kill you, it will only be a sub-second fall before you're dead. Also, the stack itself should only take about 10 seconds to build.

**Tip:** Use shears to cut leaves from trees, and build your stack out of leaf blocks for a self-destroying structure (the leaves will slowly disappear over time) in order to prevent your world filling up with random columns of blocks.

Answer (score 7):

Lava will also do the trick if you have some nearby.

Answer (score 5):

If your goal is to return to the spawn point, then the /home command might do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you are near water just dive in and sink to the bottom...

It will take a while and it will be hard to recover any items you drop.

Answer (score 0):

## 1.3.1+

Use the `/kill` command. Syntax:

```
/kill <target>
```

For example:

```
/kill Jimmy
```

If left blank it kills the person who ran it:

```
/kill
```

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 in the question, they said "something like the `kill` command in Quake-like games"