# Where are my Minecraft saves located?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to copy/modify/delete a Minecraft world. Where can I find my saves folder?

Comment: Nobody Worry found them now.

Comment: Welcome to Gaming Stack Exchange! This is not a forum. Questions you ask are retained for others to find (via, say, Google). I'm glad you found your solution independently; that doesn't stop people from answering and updating the answers. :)

Comment: Can someone fix the question title? I have no idea what "without going on Minecraft" means.

Answer (score 43):

As [the Minepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Q:_How_do_I_play_an_external_map_in_Survival_Mode.3F) mentions, your save files are in:

```
~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/saves/
```

If you were running Linux, it'd just be:

```
~/.minecraft/saves
```

If you were running Windows, instead, it'd be:

```
%APPDATA%\.minecraft\saves\
```

---

In all cases, you can reach the correct folder easily with your file manager of choice using this little trickery:

1. Start Minecraft
2. Choose "Mods and Texture packs"
3. Choose "Open texture pack folder"
4. Go up a level
5. Open the `saves` directory.

Comment: I didn't use that i used this http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100921121600AAQkoTy (the first one you said)

Comment: But i am stuck when i get to saves i click world 1 and it comes up with many folders these folders are labeled 0,1,1a,1b... and once you clicked one, it takes you to more folders which are labeled the same if you click any of them you will come across vfd files which are the ones with the traffic cone logo

Comment: @Ben as [Kevin Reid](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/5962/kevin-reid) [said](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14666/im-stuck-really-far-down-on-minecraft-how-do-i-get-back-to-the-surface/14685#14685), you only need to upload the `levels.dat` file directly into the World folder of interest.

Comment: @Ben In this case you have two answers that need a checkmark ;)

Comment: I don't think this answer applies to the Windows 10 version (Bedrock? v1.2+).  Can someone propose another answer or update?