# Cannot find "saves" folder in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I really want to install http://www.planetminecraft.com/texture_pack/adventure-time-pro-128x128/ to my minecraft. Its an adventure map. I have looked at several youtube videos on how to install it but they all say the same thing, once I get to the "go to the saves folder" i get stuck cause in my minecraft i dont have a saves folder :(
I found the hidden Library, and searched for my minecraft folder, but there isn't a saves folder inside. I'm on a Macbook Air, OS X Version 10.9.

What can I do so I can install this?

Comment: Hi Alyssa, welcome to Arqade. That link leads to a texture pack, not an adventure map. Texture packs have been replaced by resource packs in the latest versions of Minecraft. As for where your saves are, check this out - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/14703/26487 (in fact, because this is what you're asking, your question might get closed as a duplicate unless you can edit it to make it clear that the location of your saves is not the main issue)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to add your *texture pack* is to open Minecraft, then Options, then Resource Packs. You should see a button called Open Resource Pack folder. Click on that, and drag your zip into the folder that opens.

If you want to install an actual adventure map, just create a empty saves folder in your .minecraft folder and drag your map folder there.

HINT: For installing texture packs, I believe it is a bit faster to use a folder instead of a zip by putting the zip's contents into a new folder.