# Where is my Minecraft world saved?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to put a Minecraft world onto a USB stick. My problem is that when I launch Minecraft the world is there, but when I go into Minecraft saves it is not in my finder. I need this for a school project and cannot take my Mac with me to school. Any suggestions on where it might be?

Comment: First, the good news: if it's opening in Minecraft, it's saved someplace, otherwise it wouldn't be loading at all. Have you checked the locations listed at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115943/is-the-minecraft-folder-hidden-on-a-mac ?

Comment: Try checking your profile on the new launcher.  Check in the folder listed in the Minecraft directory field.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how the folder structure on a Mac is arranged, but at the very least you should have a folder named ".minecraft". Inside this folder there should be another folder called "saves". This folder contains all your saved worlds. Copy/Paste a folder grom .minecraft/saves into the same folder on a different machine, and you should be able to play on the world (ignoring issues regarding the Minecraft version or installed mods).

An easy way to get to this folder is by navigating to the Texture Pack option in the minecraft client, clicking the "Open resource pack folder" button and going up one level in the folder hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14702/where-are-my-minecraft-saves-located) before.

I will quote badp here:

> As [the Minepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Q:_How_do_I_play_an_external_map_in_Survival_Mode.3F) mentions, your save files are in:
>
> > ~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/saves/
>
> If you were running Linux, it'd just be:
>
> > ~/.minecraft/saves
>
> If you were running Windows, instead, it'd be:
>
> > %APPDATA%.minecraft\saves\
>
> In all cases, you can reach the correct folder easily with your file
> manager of choice using this little trickery:
>
> 1. Start Minecraft
> 2. Choose "Mods and Texture packs"
> 3. Choose "Open texture pack folder"
> 4. Go up a level
> 5. Open the saves directory.

Comment: you can also click edit profile before launching of mine craft and click open game Do.

Answer (score 0):

Find your ".minecraft" folder click the "worlds" folder in that. Then you will see a folder for every world you made put the one you want onto you UBS drive

Answer (score -2):

On Windows 7:

- Click Start Ball (lower left corner)
- In search box type: folder
- Look in the list for Folder Options and click it
- Click VIEW
- Click the Circle next to Show Hidden Files
- Apply & OK
- Click Start Ball (lower left corner)
- Click Computer
- Double click (C:)
- Click/goto:

  ```
  Users/<username>/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/Saves folder
  ```

Comment: *"I need this for a school project and cannot take my Mac with me to school"* this states the user is asking about a Mac, not Windows 7