# I can't find my world file in Minecraft Java for a snapshot, how do I find the world file?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to share my snapshot world with my friends, but I can't find the file itself. Where is it so I can send it to them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where are my Minecraft saves located?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14702/where-are-my-minecraft-saves-located)

Answer (score 0):

in %appdata% in a folder .minecraft
(you should see a folder in .minecraft titled saves)